# v-html receiving a prop does not render (Vue, SVG)

Tags: vue.js, svg, data-binding

I'm passing a string containing a sequence of  elements as a prop, which I try to render using :v-html="prop":

```html
<template>
  <svg
    version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 26 26"
    :class="sizeClass"
    :height="size"
    :width="size"
  >
    <g :v-html="sequence" />
  </svg>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Avatar",
  props: {
    sizeClass: String,
    size: String,
    sequence: String,
  },
});
</script>
```

However inspecting the result on dev tools, the html is not rendered, but appears only in the v-html attribute :

[image: devtools screenshot]

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directives are bound by default they don't need binding sign `:` or `v-bind:`:

```
 <g v-html="sequence" />
```